# git undo deletes but preserve new work

Tags: git

I am a sole developer on a web-based project. I commit changes locally and occasionally push to a bare repo. Since it's just me I don't have any branches to my history, only the master branch. From my live website I then pull from the bare repo after testing. All of that is working fine.

Recently I went down a development path that I would like to undo, but I don't want to lose access to the new work (so that I can re-purpose that work elsewhere in the project).

The problem is that I have deleted many files along this new path. I know that I can do a `git reset --hard` on my local repo to go back in my history to recover those deleted files, but then I lose my new work. I'm trying to figure out how to **also** keep some of the development work that I did on the files that I would like to revert. I looked at rebasing or merging, but I've not done this before and it seems that these would not accomplish what I want since my master branch has those files deleted.

Can anyone suggest a set of steps to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a **new** branch which will contain your new work. After that revert back to the commit you want.

`git branch newBranchName`

Comment: Ahh. So simple and obvious in retrospect. Thanks!